# how to extract fields with sed and regex

Tags: regex, sed

I have input that looks like this:

```
[03/Jun/applications/somejunk/morejunk/ 200
```

And I want to use sed + regex to extract it in the form:

```
03/Jun 200
```

Here's the regex I'm trying, but I can't figure out how to make extract what I want.

```
\([0-9]{2}/[a-zA-Z]{3}/\).* \([0-9]{3}\)
```

Any help would be awesome.  Here's my test code:

```
$ echo "[03/Jun/applications/somejunk/morejunk/ 200" | sed 's,\\([0-9]{2}/[a-zA-Z]{3}/\\).* \\([0-9]{3}\\),\1 \2,g'
```

Answer (score 1):

this works

```
sed 's;\[\([0-9]\{2\}/[a-zA-Z]\{3\}\)[^ ]*\(.*\);\1\2;'
```

---

```
$ echo "[03/Jun/applications/somejunk/morejunk/ 200" | sed 's;\[\([0-9]\{2\}/[a-zA-Z]\{3\}\)[^ ]*\(.*\);\1\2;'
03/Jun 200
```

match 2 digits `[0-9]\{2\}`
match a single slash `/`
match 3 letters `[a-zA-Z]\{3\}`
group them into `\1` -- that is parenthesize them
match anything until a space `[^ ]*`
match everything after the space (including the space) and hold it in `\2`
return `\1\2`
`\2` already contains a space

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
sed 's,.\([0-9]\{2\}/[a-zA-Z]\{3\}\)/.* \([0-9]\{3\}\),\1 \2,'
```

Example:

```
$ echo "[03/Jun/applications/somejunk/morejunk/ 200" | sed 's,.\([0-9]\{2\}/[a-zA-Z]\{3\}\)/.* \([0-9]\{3\}\),\1 \2,'
03/Jun 200
```